# Ubuntu 20.04 Suddenly getting 500 No space left on device errors when running apt-get update

Tags: apt, mount

I get the below output when trying to run sudo apt-get update

```
ilcoan@webpihole:~$ sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Err:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
  500  No space left on device [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]
Err:3 http://download.webmin.com/download/repository sarge InRelease
  500  No space left on device [IP: 104.207.151.13 80]
Err:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
  500  No space left on device [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]
Err:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
  500  No space left on device [IP: 91.189.91.38 80]
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/InRelease  500  No space left on device [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-backports/InRelease  500  No space left on device [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-security/InRelease  500  No space left on device [IP: 91.189.91.38 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://download.webmin.com/download/repository/dists/sarge/InRelease  500  No space left on device [IP: 104.207.151.13 80]
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
ilcoan@webpihole:~$ ilcoan@webpihole:~$ sudo apt-get update
  500  No space left on device [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]
Err:3 http://download.webmin.com/download/repository sarge InRelease
  500  No space left on device [IP: 104.207.151.13 80]
Err:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
  500  No space left on device [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]
Err:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
  500  No space left on device [IP: 91.189.91.38 80]
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/InRelease  500  No space left on device [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-backports/InRelease  500  No space left on device [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-security/InRelease  500  No space left on device [IP: 91.189.91.38 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://download.webmin.com/download/repository/dists/sarge/InRelease  500  No space left on device [IP: 104.207.151.13 80]
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

The output of command sudo df -h

```
ilcoan@webpihole:~$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs           1.6G  1.3M  1.6G   1% /run
/dev/sda2       147G   11G  129G   8% /
tmpfs           7.9G  5.9M  7.9G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0       56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/1988
/dev/loop1       56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/1997
/dev/loop2       73M   73M     0 100% /snap/lxd/19766
/dev/loop3       33M   33M     0 100% /snap/snapd/11588
/dev/loop4       33M   33M     0 100% /snap/snapd/11402
/dev/loop5       69M   69M     0 100% /snap/lxd/19823
tmpfs           1.6G     0  1.6G   0% /run/user/997
tmpfs           1.6G     0  1.6G   0% /run/user/1000
```

And the output of df -i

```
ilcoan@webpihole:~$ df -i
Filesystem      Inodes  IUsed   IFree IUse% Mounted on
udev           2038590    446 2038144    1% /dev
tmpfs          2049689    773 2048916    1% /run
/dev/sda2      9830400 156872 9673528    2% /
tmpfs          2049689     15 2049674    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs          2049689      6 2049683    1% /run/lock
tmpfs          2049689     18 2049671    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0       10817  10817       0  100% /snap/core18/1988
/dev/loop1       10790  10790       0  100% /snap/core18/1997
/dev/loop2        1586   1586       0  100% /snap/lxd/19766
/dev/loop3         474    474       0  100% /snap/snapd/11588
/dev/loop4         474    474       0  100% /snap/snapd/11402
/dev/loop5        1586   1586       0  100% /snap/lxd/19823
tmpfs          2049689     22 2049667    1% /run/user/997
tmpfs          2049689     22 2049667    1% /run/user/1000
```

Please help me to understand what is causing the NO SPACE issue when nothing is full? I am thoroughly confused. I have spent HOURS on this by scouring the web and I have tried most everything that has been stated for this issue but nothing at all will allow this to work.

Comment: Hi and welcome. Is this your IP *IP: 91.189.91.39 80

Comment: No! These must belong to Ubuntu. @David

Comment: FYI I even spun up a BRAND new Ubuntu Server VM and immediately tried an apt-get update and it failed as well. However I can go to http://us.archive.ubuntu.com and peruse the files at that location. I am so confused as to what may be causing this.